# Create folder and install software using puppet

Tags: puppet

Suppose I have a vm running on my pc. My vm has puppet installed. Now I want to install firefox on my pc not in my vm. I know to install firefox I can just do `sudo apt-get install firefox` on my pc but I want to run this command from my vm using puppet. How can I do that? or can I do something like (code below is just an idea if something like this is possible?)

```
package { 'firefox':
 ensure   => 'present',
 provider => '....',
}
```

Also I want to create a folder 'test' in my pc. Again I can do this by running commands `cd ~` and `sudo mkdir test`. But I want to create the folder using puppet. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's exactly how you install a package, also to create a directory you will need to do something like this: file { '/your/dir/path': ensure => directory, }

Moreover, this 2 resources may take additional parameters for example the file resource might have an owner or some permissions assigned to it which will look something like:

```
file { '/your/dir/path':
  ensure => directory,
  owner  => root,
  mode   => 700,
}
```